# Displaying an image uploaded with CarrierWave using image_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, image-uploading, carrierwave

I'm trying to upload pictures to my rails app using the carrierwave gem, but can't figure out how to get the photos to display with the image_tag helper. I'm actually not sure if the photos are uploading because I get a NoMethodError for .image_url. The photos model belongs to the places model.

```html
<%= simple_form_for @photo, url: place_photos_path(@place) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :caption %>
  <%= f.input :picture %>
  <%= f.submit "Add a photo", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>

<% if @place.photos.any? %>
      <% @place.photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= photo.caption%>
        <%= image_tag photo.image_url.to_s if photo.image_url.present? %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

```html
class Photo < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :place

      mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader


end

class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  
  storage :file
  
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  
  class Place < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_many :photos


    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :address, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you post your model and uploader code it will make bit easier to trace down the problem:

I believe you are using this code as specified in carrierwave documentation:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :picture, ImageUploader
end
```

Then all you have to do is use this:

```
<%= image_tag photo.picture.url, class: 'class-name' %>
```

For more information about uploader read from here https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#getting-started

Comment: I added my models above. using <%= image_tag Photo.picture.url, class: 'class-name' %> gave me a NoMethodError for .picture

Comment: Use this code and make sure the picture is actually being uploaded meaning it is not giving any error in console: use('photo' not 'Photo')
<%= image_tag photo.picture.url, class: 'class-name' %>

Comment: use https://github.com/trusche/httplog gem to log your http request in console.

Answer (score 0):

In your picture_uploader.rb

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  #uncomment this line
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick 
  storage :file

  def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end  
end
```